# How did Wall-E keep his memory of Eve when he was rebuilt?

Tags: wall-e

Wall-E suffered some pretty severe injuries and needed a large chunk of his circuitry replaced. How did he retain (or regain) his memory of Eve after he had been rebuilt, and was her 'kiss' somehow responsible for these memories coming back?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your title suggests a pretty good question, but you shouldn't answer it in the body.  Start with the title, and then progress to a synopsis of everything we know about how he was destroyed and rebuilt, and leave it at that; your question shouldn't include your answer.  If you think you have the answer, you should self-answer your question, including all the additional evidence you have to support your answer.  Maybe other people will agree, or maybe someone else will post a better answer.  You should take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Hi and welcome! @DavidW is spot on with his comment. When you've read the [tour] and you're ready you can [edit] your question.

Comment: @DavidW Removed answer.

Comment: to equate to a computer: his case and power supply were broken, the hard drive was fine

Comment: I think the original question was fine, you just needed to not phrase it as its own answer.

Comment: @NKCampbell His motherboard was broken as well.

Comment: motherboard is just the skeleton that all the parts plug into ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell - A million mobo designers are spinning in their graves at that statement.

Comment: @Valorum haha Woz just knocked on my door and punched me in the face

Answer (score 13):

This was discussed by the film's production team; Bill Wise (character supervisor), Lindsey Collins (co-producer), Derek Thompson (story artist), Angus MacLane (storyboard artist), in the film's commentary track.

> **BW:** If he has a consciousness, what part does it live in, if he can replace all his parts?
> **LC:** It lives in that little deck!
> **DT:** It lives inside his chest. I believe that his brain is inside his chest. So that's where his soul is. So if that gets destroyed, he gets no...
> **BW:** Yeah. ... It's gotta be in his chest, but [uncertain] then that gets fried.
> **DT:** That's a good point. But it gets damaged, but not totally destroyed.

**It stands to reason that the circuits that were damaged didn't have direct responsibility for his memory (where his faulty romantic software resides), but rather some other vital system, in this case almost certainly his power supply.**

---

The [script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html) refers to the damage occurring to his "*chest circuitry*" (e.g. analogous to the human heart or lungs).

> Wall-E's chest circuitry blows out.
> He wheezes...
> ...then drops lifelessly down the chute.

And the damage results in his power warning coming on.

> The WALL-As light up a SMALL WORK SPACE.
> Eve props Wall-E up against some trash.
> He's barely functioning.
> Fades in and out of consciousness.
> Just his red "warning" light flashes on his meter.

Her fix helps with this problem, but he still needs to be charged due to the power loss from the short circuiting.

> ...SPARE PARTS being grabbed by Eve...
> ...Frantically installs the new parts into Wall-E...
> ...Her arms a blur of precision in motion...
> ...Replaces his damaged CIRCUIT BOARD. The final piece...
> ...She opens his new solar panels...
> ...and BLASTS a hole in the ceiling with her gun.

Once he's charged, his program reboots. It just takes a little (and probably unneeded) nudge from Eve to get his faulty software to go back to its earlier state. There's no indication (from the script or the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3359002-wall-e-disney-pixar-wall-e)) that *programming* passed between them, just a small amount of static electricity.

The director's commentary described it as depicting...

> *"... love, the mysterious element, and the science of there just being a missing 'spark', a last minute little kind of defibrillator kind of jolt, to kick in the last circuit in Wall-E, so this hand-holding and a kiss (or the equivalent of a kiss, by them touching and a little electric shock) I felt the audience would want and would buy, and that that last little equation was the missing step for Wall-E to fully come back"*

Comment: I.e. the cached backup of the romantic logic was in his non-volatile SSD deep inside his chassis, protecting it from damage. Just too a system restore after the main board replacement and he was back!